# How to enable infopath forms service in SharePoint 2019 on-premises

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath, 2019

We have SharePoint 2019 on-premise server. I found that the InfoPath Forms Service in General Application Setting is not available, also in List setting the Form setting feature is not available.

How to enable InfoPath forms service in SharePoint 2019 on-premises?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately InfoPath is deprecated in SharePoint 2019. Please check this link:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/what-s-new/what-s-deprecated-or-removed-from-sharepoint-server-2019

Comment: It is deprecated but not removed

Comment: Yes, but I'm not recommend use InfoPath. It's really pain for support.

Comment: @Viktor Buzin Yes, I agree..